# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories: /storage/emulated/0/Download/ on Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I Want To Download And save file from my url to external storage download directory in Android 10.
I have used this code to download.

```
    public void StartNewDownload(String url) {

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDescription("Downloading Profile"); 
    request.setTitle("Abc App");
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ File.separator, "parag.jpeg"); 

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request); 

}
```

it shows error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.abc, PID: 15197
>
> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories: /storage/emulated/0/Download/
>     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2079)
>     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
>     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
>     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
>     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:658)
>     at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:558)
>     at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:546)
>     at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:569)
>     at com.example.abc.Activity.showDetails.StartNewDownload(showDetails.java:102)
>     at com.example.abc.Activity.showDetails$1.onClick(showDetails.java:68)
> ```

But if i use

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+ File.separator , "parag.jpeg");
```

this downloads the file but in my app specific folder 
but i want to download the file in external public download directory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

as per your code [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) API is deprecated.

use the below code to save the file in the standard directory.

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,"parag.jpeg")
```

it will try to save to the standard directory

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/files/Pictures/parag.jpg
```

> For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above,
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not needed and the dirType must
>   be one of the known public directories like
>   Environment#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, Environment#DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
>   Environment#DIRECTORY_MOVIES, etc.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I downgraded  my  targetSdkVersion and  compileSdkVersion from 29 to 28 with  buildToolsVersion "29.0.3" in my case. Working now.

Answer (score 5):

First of all add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml file inside application tag.

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Use `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` or any Environment that Appropriate to your file.

```
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE
        )
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Krishan Demo") //Download Manager Title
            .setDescription("Downloading...") // Download manager Discription
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, // It can be any stanaderd directory Like DCIM,Downloads etc...
                "/KrishanImages/testing.jpg" // Your Custom directory name/Your Image file name
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to save the file.

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileType)
```

Answer (score -2):

It Work for Me

in manifest
**android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**
For Android  below v28 and v28+

```
  String folder = "/Download";
                    try { //V28 Below
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(folder, filename);//v 28 allow to create and it deprecated method(v28+)

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        //For Android  28+
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);//(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,"picname.jpeg")
                    }
```

Comment: Must Add in manifest
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />